# Change text dynamically in a preloader with Framework7

Tags: jquery, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am using `framework7` in one of me project with `PhoneGap`

I am opening a dialog with this code:

```
  myApp.dialog.preloader("my text");
```

but now I want to change the text dynamically, so I have this code

```
 myApp.dialog.preloader.setText("my new text");
```

But it does not work, and I get this error:

> myApp.dialog.preloader.setText is not a function

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried setText('my new text') ?

https://framework7.io/docs/dialog.html some useful examples at bottom with demo

Comment: thanks @DavitMikuchadze , tried but does not work

Answer (score 0):

app.dialog.preloader('Custom text');

is indeed the correct way to handle the preloader title (see https://framework7.io/docs/dialog.html#preloader for more details).

If you want to vary the title of preloader you can consider to pass a variable as argument of your function:

```
app.dialog.preloader(customText);
```

and vary `customText` value.

It may not be very elegant, but it's effective.